# How to override v-select input icon

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to change the default material design icon in v-select from `mdi-menu-down` to `mdi-chevron-down`. How do I do that?

I managed to hide the default icon by using `::v-deep` like this

```
::v-deep .custom-input-append .v-input__append-inner{
display: none;
}
```

Please take a look at the image below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to change CSS directly. Just use `append-icon` prop:

```js
<v-select
  :items="items"
  label="Standard"
  append-icon="mdi-chevron-down"
></v-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

To globally override for all v-selects using mdi fonts as an example (vuetify 2):

```
new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi',
        values: {
            dropdown: 'mdi-chevron-down'
        }
    }
})
```

because the doc states that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaldn.png)

The default icon is: `$dropdown` so we can override this icon the above mentioned way. (and many others the same way)

Also find available presets here (in mdi file in our case):
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/tree/v2-stable/packages/vuetify/src/services/icons/presets